# error: Ordinal 139 could not be located in swscale-2.dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ffmpeg

Nominally an ffmpeg issue but it could be an issue with versions of standard windows libraries & VS

Running Win 7, VS2010;  my program uses ffmpeg libraries and dlls so I just upgraded ffmpeg library to ffmpeg-1.1.1 win 32 dev for libraries and win32-shared for dlls.

Ran my program under debug mode and it runs fine.  Changed to Release mode, recompiled all and tried to run.  Immediately I get the error message Ordinal 139 could not be located in swscale-2.dll

Using same dlls for both runs [well, I copied them over from Debug folder to Release folder.  Twice] as when I ran in Debug mode.

Any clues?  This one has me stumped.

---

so i am comparing the property pages between debug and release.

- both have multi-theaded debug set (c++/code geneeration)
- release mode has Liner Optimization references set to Yes /OPT:REF whereas debug has nothing;

==> set it to NO and did not get the error message re Ordinal 39 not found.

Answer (score 0):

It can hardly be anything different from use of wrong files. If you build them yourself, make sure that:

- you use the correct DLL and LIB files produced by FFmpeg build
- your application loads the correct DLLs, e.g. not the ones located in \Windows\system32 installed by third party software

You can also use Dependency Walker to identify mismatches and to check whether the swscale.dll you are trying to use really have the exported function in question.

Comment: as i explained the Debug and Release versions use the same lib and same dlls. so it was something else.

Answer (score 0):

the suggestion of different lib and dlls was wrong.  the suggestion to recompile the libraries is wrong because essentially ffmpeg uses some Linux like constructs and can be compiled for windows only with difficulty, hence the use of their lib and dlls.

Here is the correct answer which i found only in a painful way -- do not delete this as it is in fact the correct answer for anyone who is stuck with an bug of  "Ordinal xxx could not be found i yyyy.dll"

so i am comparing the property pages between debug and release.

both have multi-theaded debug set (c++/code geneeration)
release mode has Liner Optimization references set to Yes /OPT:REF whereas debug has nothing;
==> set it to NO and did not get the error message re Ordinal 39 not found.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue with ffmpeg compiled for windows. It was always a dll/lib mismatch. Even tough my main exe linked to the the correct ffmpeg libs, some dll or lib in my project was not using the new compiled ffmpeg libs. So you might have compiled your debug dependencies correctly and not your release ones.